# Separate items in a list (or dictionary or counter *not sure XD)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

My code:

```
list1 = []
for line in open('live.txt'):
    name = line.strip()
    list1.append(name)


import collections
print("Original List : ",list1)
ctr = collections.Counter(list1)
print(ctr)
```

Output:

```
Original List :  ['Heart', 'Thumbs up', 'Thumbs up', 'Smile', 'Heart', 'Thumbs down', 'Smile']
Counter({'Heart': 2, 'Thumbs up': 2, 'Smile': 2, 'Thumbs down': 1})
```

Well my problem is that I want to separate the items in the list so the output will look like this:

> Heart: 2
>   Thumbs up: 2
>   Smile: 2
>   Thumbs down: 1

Comment: Have you tried *anything* to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you should just iterate through a dictiory

```
for key in ctr:
  print(key, ': ', ctr[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want :

```
import collections

list1 = [line.strip() for line in open('live.txt')]

ctr = collections.Counter(list1)
for key,value in ctr.items():
     print(key, ' : ', value)
```